# Django seems to be using incorrect settings module

Tags: python, django

Something strange has happened in my django app and I can't seem to trace it back to a particular change.

Whenever I run `python manage.py runserver`, I get this error:

```
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

My settings module is configured properly -- I have `DEBUG=True` and I have also set `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

I continued to investigate and it seems like somehow, Django has decided to import the wrong settings module.

When I do `from django.conf import settings` and I print `settings.__dict__`, I see this:

```
{'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us', 'LOGGING': {}, 'DEBUG': False, 'USE_I18N': True, 'INSTALLED_APPS': ('django_nose',), 'FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME': None, 'LOGGING_CONFIG': 'logging.config.dictConfig', '_wrapped': <Settings "django.conf.global_settings">}
```

It seems like `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is somehow being set to `django.conf.global_settings`.

I've tried to override this by settings `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` explicitly in manage.py, but this doesn't seem to fix anything (though the env. variable does appear to be set properly after this). However, I still get the same bizarre value for my settings file.

I've also tried uninstalling `django-nose`, thinking that this might be the culprit (as it seems to be the only app installed in this bizarre settings file). But that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable explicitly before starting the server?

Comment: I am setting it explicitly in `manage.py`. I have also tried settings it in bash via `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings`. While it appears to set it properly, django still imports the wrong module (as in `django.conf.settings` is wrong).